# Are the firewall and forward pressure bulkhead different components?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-structures

Suppose in a single engine aircraft, where the engine is located near the nose of the aircraft. If the cabin is pressurized, I know there will be a requirement of pressure bulkheads, both in the rear and the front to prevent the excess pressure from leaking out (and bearing the pressurization stresses). Now my question is that is the firewall, which is used to keep the heat of the engine (and flames if the engine ignites) away from other components of the aircraft, same as the forward pressure bulkhead i.e. does the firewall in this case have 2 roles: being heat resistant and at the same time bearing the pressurization stresses due to excess pressure inside the cabin.